# Finding local maxima in a 2D array

Tags: algorithm, max

A local maximum in a 2D array can be defined as a value such that all it's 4 neighbours are less than or equal to it, ie, for `a[i][j]` to be a local maximum,

```
a[i+1][j] <= a[i][j] 
&& a[i-1][j] <= a[i][j]
&& a[i][j+1] <= a[i][j]
&& a[i+1][j-1] <= a[i][j]
```

I was asked to find all the local maxima in a given 2D array.

The naive way to do this would be to just go through all the elements, and checking whether or not each element is a local maximum. This would be O( n^2 ). I feel that you cannot do better than this, although my friend insists that an asymptotically better algorithm should exist. Any hints ?

I was thinking along the lines of Divide and Conquer, yet I feel that it would be impossible to detect all the local maxima without going through all the numbers, which would necessarily be O( n^2 ). Am I right or am I missing out on something ?

Comment: If you just want one of the local maxima, it can be found in less than n^2 time.

Comment: @Habisoft have given the best answer

Comment: Note that this description of local maximum is flawed. It is necessary to add to this requirement that the neighbor, if equal, must also be a local maximum. That is, it is necessary to recursively scan the equal neighbors to verify that none of them has a larger neighbor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this cannot be solved in less than O(n^2) comparisons. Assume a chess board 2d matrix where all the white squares are 1 and blacks are 0. It wiil will have O(n^2) solutions and each solution requires at least one comparison.

Comment: Thank you, your example really clarifies everything nicely :)

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, since the array is not stated as being 'square' it is really only `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of elements such that `n = i * j`. This understanding is something I would be looking for if I were the interviewer.

Comment: @arya This answer is incorrect. consider the response I provide.

Comment: @kasavbere (n-1)*(n-1) is still O(n^2) einstein!

Comment: @ElKamina (n-1)*(n-1) is not what my post says. Did you read the post? the (I-2)*(J-2) is just the starting point of optimization. Plus your post says "It wiil will have O(n^2) solutions and each solution requires at least one comparison." a false observation.

Comment: @kasavbere What can I say. You do not understand the concept of computational complexity. 10000n, n, 0.00001n are all O(n). In your case you are just reducing the co-efficient (reduction is also questionable), but you are not reducing the core complexity.

Comment: the arguments you used to justify your conclusion reveals your thought process, which as posted is not correct: You don't have to visit every element!

Comment: @kasavbere What is the meaning of visiting? If I do a comparison like A[i]<A[i+1], I am visiting both A[i] and A[i+1] right? Similarly to confirm if a element A[i][j] is a minima you need to make the following comparisons: A[i][j]<A[i+1][j], A[i][j]<A[i-1][j], A[i][j]<A[i][j+1] and A[i][j]<A[i][j-1] . So, in effect, although you are already "accessing" all those elements right? Anyways, IMHO, brush up your complexity theory basics. You need it.

Answer (score 15):

Just a heads up, local maxima or minima of a 2D grid can be computed in O(nlgn) time using a divide and conquer strategy. This is a slightly better time bound than the brute force algorithm contained in the O(n^2) time complexity class. Furthermore, improvements can be made to the divide and conquer algorithm to obtain an O(n) algorithm for the 2D grid extrema finding.

Check out these notes on the theory behind such peak picking algorithms (I am sure their are more materials out there):

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf

Comment: Your solution doesn't find all the local maxima, only a local maxima. Consider a matrix I * J only containing the value 5 in every cell, you will need to visit every all I * J cells to make sure that there is not a 4 or 6 in the matrix somewhere.

Comment: it is the better approach to go with

Comment: @HabiSoft your solution seems to work fine and  solves the 1D array in O(log n), can you also post pseudo code for finding local maxima in 2D matrix, I having problem in understating it just by reading the content.

Comment: Explanation of the 2D algorithm is given in the provided link.

If I recall correctly, it may be as simple as applying the 1D algorithm across all the columns of the nxn matrix, which would imply apply the O(log n) algorithm n times, which would yield an O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: The question asks "find **all** the local maxima", not "find one local maximum". In 1D it is possible to have n/2 local maxima, so you cannot find them all in O(log n) time.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your array is square, your solution is actually `O(I * J)` not `O( n^2 )`. Strictly speaking you only have `N` elements in your 2d array thus this solution is `O(N)`. The only way it could be `O( n^2 )` is if the array was square such that `I = J = N`.

Since the compare is `<=` rather than `<`, you need still need to check the next element any shortcuts you try will likely be processor specific.

> The worst case is that the entire array is a local maxima because the
>   entire array equals the same value.

Thus you must visit every element once, making it `O(N)`

To improve real world performance in this you would need to use pointers to access you array as in most languages 2d arrays perform considerably worse than 1d arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question can be answered using what is known as adversary arguments, which gives you a lower bound on the number of comparisons.

And in my opinion, you are right.. this would require atleast n^2 comparisons.

Comment: @kasavbere- I meant atleast n^2 only.. we are talking about lower bounds here.

Answer (score 0):

You are given an array of size 4 x 4. You will need to do the following task.

1. Fill the array with some random numbers using rand() function.
2. For each cell (i,j) your will need to find the cell with maximum number among all the possible neighbors the cell (i,j) has.
3. Then put that maximum number in the that cell (i,j)

Sample Input:

```
177 -90 12 7
1 34 43 67
11 11 122 45
6 90 98 93
```

Sample Output:

```
34 177 67 67
177 177 122 122
90 122 98 122
90 98 122 122
```

Answer (score -1):

YOU DO NOT HAVE TO VISIT EVERY ELEMENT:

All you have to do is visualize the grid and you will see that this can be solved in much less than a flat n^2 (or I*J). 
Here are the optimizations, by level:

1] for an I*J matrix, you need only search (I-2)*(J-2). Why? the borders cannot be maxima because of the undefined elements:

```
 e.g. grid[0][J] or grid[I][0] could never be maxima. because of the -1 neighbor.
```

So for a 10 by 12 grid, instead of visiting all 120 elements, we are looking at 80 elements.

2] if grid[I][J] is a maximum, then we can skip all cells adjacent to [I][J] as we continue the search. This will further reduce the number of elements to compare.

Hence, the answer is no, you don't have to visit every element.

Comment: While your optimizations are correct, your algorithm is still going to be O(i*j). First, reducing the number of checks by eliminating the border is effective for relatively small grids (33% for 10x12) but does little for larger ones. On a 100x120 grid, you go from 12000 squares to 11564, which is < 4%. You second optimization doesn't actually do anything in the case where there are no local maxima.

Comment: That's correct. The point here is the basis for a conclusion is as important as the conclusion itself. Using false arguments to arrive at correct conclusions should not be good enough.

Comment: What's incorrect with the reasoning ? ElKamino just concludes, with a good example, and shows how this is O(n^2). And yes, you show some optimizations, and I think we can conclude that the required optimal and complete algorithm has to be Θ(n^2).

Comment: The other guy did say "It wiil will have O(n^2) solutions and each solution requires at least one comparison." I too think rigor is important.

Comment: As I cover in my answer, your point `2]` is incorrect, because the test is <= such that `a[i+1][j] <= a[i][j]` meaning if the entire matrix is the same value, then every cell is a maxima.

Comment: In mathematics, when you compute the local maximum on a given domain, points on the boundary can usually be considered to be local maxima. E.g. I would say that the function `f(x) = x` on the domain `[0,1]` has the local maxima `x = 1`, because at that point, the function has a greater value than for any other adjacent point within the domain. Similarly, I would say that the 1 x 2 array `[4 5]` has a local maximum at the 5.  I agree however, that the posted specifications are rather unclear about how boundaries should be handled.

Comment: And even with these questionable optimizations, the ideal case (where every element investigated is found to be a maximum, making it possible to discard 4 neighbours) runtime complexity would be `O((n -2)^2 / 4) = O(n^2)`. Which is still the same runtime complexity as the original brute force algorithm...

Answer (score -1):

Above answers just defend a mathematical model.
Which result from a simplistic view of the problem.

If you work as a programmer, you should know what a processor can do.
And you should be aware that code runs in a thread.
You should wonder if a task is sub-dividable in smaller tasks, so you be able to work it out multi-threaded and get near a 1/total-threads execution speed-up.

The code to do that depends on the language, so I don't provide an example here.

But you have to keep in mind that all values should be processed if your dealing with white noise or chessboards, so then there is no escape to do the problem faster. Only if your data is different like wheater pressure data, or finding bullseye in random placed dart boards, then you can create algo's that dont need to check every value (finding gradients problems), or using statistical analysis