# Set local maxima in 2d array to 255 and rest to 0 on single axis

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2d numpy array. I would like to set all off the local maxima of that array to `255` and all the rest to `0`. I am interested in doing this in `y` axis.

I am aware of `np.where(???, 255, 0)` and `scipy.signal.argelextrema` but I cant figure out how to make those work together.

Example:

```
input = np.array([
  [-33, -57, -77, -83, -70, -42,  -5,  45, 107, 160, 183, 172],
  [-35, -60, -80, -85, -70, -42,  -4,  46, 106, 160, 183, 172],
  [-36, -64, -84, -88, -72, -41,  -4,  45, 105, 158, 181, 173]
])
```

Result:

```
output = np.array([
  [0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 255, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 255, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 255, 0]
])
```

Comment: like this: ```array *= 255/np.max(array)
array[array<np.max(array)] = 0```

Comment: I am looking for local maxima not max values, my array currently have positive and negative values. I want to turn most extreme, locally, in both directions to 255. But I will see what I can do with the solution you suggested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781328/finding-local-maxima-in-a-2d-array\

Comment: Ive added example

Comment: `copyable, named and typed format.` I don't know what that means. Yes peaks in only 1D - if I am not mistaken this is y axis - basically I would like to go and find peaks in the rows. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both local maxima and minima, this code does the trick, I think it is reliable and fast.

```
import numpy as np
diff = np.diff(input, axis=1)
output = np.zeros_like(input)
output[:, 1:-1] = 255*(diff[:, 1:]*diff[:, :-1] < 0)
print(output)
```